# How do you filter a composite key in the where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause, dml

I'm trying to filter a query using a composite key, however, I'm not sure how to filter using the compound key in the where clause. `XSiteProductItemId` and `MercuryProductItemId` make up a compound key that identify a unique row.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT VMPOrdersExtract.XSiteProductItemId
  ,  VMPOrdersExtract.MercuryProductItemId
FROM Appraisal.ext.VMPOrders AS VMPOrdersExtract
LEFT JOIN dw.DimAppraisal DimApprasial ON DimApprasial.XsiteProductItemId = VMPOrdersExtract.XSiteProductItemId
  AND DimApprasial.MercuryProductItemId = VMPOrdersExtract.MercuryProductItemId
WHERE VMPOrdersExtract.LastSyncDateTime > DimApprasial.LastSyncDateTime
OR (
    VMPOrdersExtract.XSiteProductItemId
    AND VMPOrdersExtract.MercuryProductItemId
) is null
```

Clearly my `OR` condition in the `WHERE` clause is syntactically incorrect. How can I filter only the composite key records that are `null` or don't exist in the `DimAppraisal` table?

Comment: SELECT VMPOrdersExtract.XSiteProductItemId, 
VMPOrdersExtract.MercuryProductItemId
FROM Appraisal.ext.VMPOrders AS VMPOrdersExtract
LEFT JOIN dw.DimAppraisal DimApprasial ON DimApprasial.XsiteProductItemId = 
VMPOrdersExtract.XSiteProductItemId
AND DimApprasial.MercuryProductItemId = 
VMPOrdersExtract.MercuryProductItemId
WHERE VMPOrdersExtract.LastSyncDateTime > DimApprasial.LastSyncDateTime
OR (VMPOrdersExtract.XSiteProductItemId is null AND 
VMPOrdersExtract.MercuryProductItemId is null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
WHERE VMPOrdersExtract.LastSyncDateTime > DimApprasial.LastSyncDateTime
OR (VMPOrdersExtract.XSiteProductItemId IS NULL AND 
VMPOrdersExtract.MercuryProductItemId IS NULL);
```

Comment: Such a simple solution that I'm now laughing at myself. :)  Thanks!

Comment: @PJ.SQL Consider to accept the answer solve your issue :)

Comment: I got you. Just have to wait for the minimum time limit to pass. :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding it to the answer as well ;)

```
 SELECT VMPOrdersExtract.XSiteProductItemId, VMPOrdersExtract.MercuryProductItemId 
FROM Appraisal.ext.VMPOrders AS VMPOrdersExtract LEFT JOIN dw.DimAppraisal DimApprasial 
ON DimApprasial.XsiteProductItemId = VMPOrdersExtract.XSiteProductItemId AND 
DimApprasial.MercuryProductItemId = VMPOrdersExtract.MercuryProductItemId WHERE 
VMPOrdersExtract.LastSyncDateTime > DimApprasial.LastSyncDateTime OR 
(VMPOrdersExtract.XSiteProductItemId is null AND VMPOrdersExtract.MercuryProductItemId is null)
```